# How to get more current from 555 timer?

Tags: transistors, current, dc-motor, 555

My power supply is filtered regulated 5 volt 500 mA . I am using a 555 in monostable mode to switch the motor on for a certain amount of time after the 555 is trigerred. (The 555 is being trigerred by a counter circuit). But the output current from the 555 is too low. How can I use a transistor like 2N3055 to get full 500mA current? What other ways are there to achieve the same thing?

[image: Will This Work?]
**Will this work?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An emitter follower will have a voltage in the emitter about 0.6v lower than the voltage at the base. It will work if you don't have a problem with the reduced voltage level.
Note that a 555 with 5v supply can have an output as low as 3v depending on the output current.

The alternative is to use a transistor or mosfet as a low side switch (switching the ground side of the load)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2filn37.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The mosfet will be a better solution (more efficient) because it has a lower voltage drop across it (drain-source), and it doesn't need a constant current in the gate (for static operation) as the transistor does.
Just select a logic level Nmosfet so that it can turn fully on with low resistance

Comment: Values of the resistors, transistors mosfets...?

Comment: You can use any logic level mosfet, just visit any vendor or eshop and use the filters to select a device that suits your needs making sure it can be fully turned on with 3-4v Vgs. Regarding R2, it should be calculated for a base current of about 1/10 to 1/20 of the collector current so that the transistor is saturated and has a low Vce drop.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm the mosfet solution works well.  I used a similar approach to driving a set of CNC stepper motors, and used mosfets as switches driven by a low current device like a 555 (it was a microprocessor, but the issue is the same).  I used a generic mosfet I got at radio shack (IRF510 perhaps).  The current ratings on mosfets go up into the whole amps range.

Comment: Per http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf the high-level output can be as low as 2 volts.

Comment: @JoeRounceville IRF510 will not work well in this case, It requires a Vgs in the level of 8v or so, definitely not a logic level mosfet. Also the Rds-on is on the high side 0.54 Ohm at Vgs=10v.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yes it can be that low but for a mosfet in static operation (as opposed to PWM) the voltage will hardly drop because it just needs to change the mosfet gate capoacitance and then there is no gate current.

Comment: I thought the threshold voltage for IRF510 was like 4v.  It may not have been IRF510, but it was definitely one of those cheapy mosfets you can get at radio shack.

Comment: @JoeRounceville The threshold voltage is not a good level to use when driving the mosfet. It is specified for VDS=VGS and Id=250μA. In order to get a voltage drop of 3-4v across a resistance with just 250μA the resistance must be about 12k, that is an approximation of the Rds-on at that Vgs voltage.

Comment: @alexan_e I tried option two, as I dont have a MOSFET in my stock. But I am getting a voltage of ony 1 volt accross the diode. Do you think changing R2 will yeild better results? I used R2 = 100 ohm.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha What is the value of the base resistor? Note that you need to calculate it for a current of about 1/10 to 1/20 of the motor, in other words for 1A output you should choose the resistor for 50-100mA base current.

Comment: @alexan_e the base resistor(R2) i used is 100ohm. But I dont think that is what you are looking for... Can you be more specific? The output voltage is now only 1 volt.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha The output voltage drops when the base current vs output current is not high enough. The base current is about (Vbase-0.6v)/Rbase so if we assume 3v output from 555 (because it drops as you source current) the base current will be (3v-0.6v)/100 Ohm= 24mA that should be good enough for up to 0.4A or so. Are you sure the power supply has enough current to drive the motor and what is the motor current requirement?

Comment: The power supply has a 1 amp transformer but as I used a 7805 , the output is 500 mA and 5 volt (I am not absolutely sure) . And the output from across the diode is only about 1 volt. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha Can you measure the voltage at the 555 output? Which transistor are you using? Also double check that the base resistor is 100 Ohm.

Comment: i am using 2N3055 transistor. And yeah Brown Black Brown it is.

Comment: @alexan_e the 555 output is 3.5 volt. Transistor is 3055. resistor is 100 ohm. Which gives 29 mA of base current right? So what is the problem?

Comment: @alexan_e is something wrong with the transistor I am using?

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha I think your motor requires more current than 0.4-0.5A, can you connect it directly to the 5v supply and measure the current?

Comment: @alexan_e Sure... wait a sec

Comment: @alexan_e I am sorry ... The problem wasn't with anything else it was a loose wire... Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @alexan_e But the standby voltage is little more than 2 volts, is it normal? shouldnt it be zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16242/discussion-between-soumadeep-saha-and-alexan-e).

Comment: I just checked the board I built for my CNC driver circuit.  It was a RFP12N10L mosfet, and it seems unlikely radio shack would stock that... so I must be thinking about something else.

Answer (score 4):

As a high side driver, the 555 is only rated for something like 100 mA, and it takes a good sized output voltage hit at that current, so it'll never work directly as a motor driver.

The emitter follower you've shown is better, but you can't drive it into saturation so you'll still lose about a volt across the transistor when it's on, starving your motor somewhat.

If you use a P channel MOSFET with a reasonable Rds(on) for the high side driver then you'll get nearly all of the 5V supply across the motor when the MOSFET turns on, plus it'll dissipate very little power.

The circuit shown below assumes you're stuck with a high side driver, and it'll work with a bipolar 555. The LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tnjzoq4e3id840/555%20motor%20driver.asc) if you want to play with the circuit, and if you want to switch to a low side driver get rid of Q1B and replace R6 with the motor and D2.

Just as an aside, the FDS4559 is a pair of about 3 amp MOSFETs in the same package, one P channel and one N channel for less than a dollar in onesies at DigiKey.

[image]

Comment: +1 A simple output booster with a lot of 'potential', EMF.

Comment: Thanks. :-)  It seems like it'll work nicely for the 'current' application.

Answer (score 2):

Using the transistor as an emitter follower will work, but you'll only get about 4.3 V at the output, because of the 0.7V drop of the transistor's B-E junction.

If possible, it would be better to put the load on the "high side" of the transistor — between the +5V supply and the collector, with the emitter tied directly to ground. You'll also need a resistor in series with the transistor's base to limit the current. 100Ω would give you a base current of 50 mA, which should be plenty.

For even lower loss, substitute an N-channel MOSFET for the NPN transistor.

Comment: That was my thought, too, but the NE555 minimum Vout with a 5V supply is about 2.75V

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I don't understand what point you are trying to make. The minimum Vout is at the maximum Iout (which is about 200 mA for a regular, non-CMOS device). The 555 should be capable of driving either the BJT or the FET to very close to 5V.

Answer (score 1):

> **Will this work?**

Nope. Not even close. Take a look at the [NE555 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) p.5 "High level output voltage". Although you are using an extra transistor to reduce the load on the 555, it demonstrates that the output is not good at sourcing current. Add the base-emitter drop in the transistor (~.7 volts), and you are not certain at all of getting a good motor drive. This, on the other hand, will:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftkbmP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Depending on how much the motor draws, R6 may need to be decreased. This will certainly work to 150 mA.

Note that you can simplify the circuit if you use a PNP for the output stage. Then Q3 goes away, and the collector of Q2 becomes the motor +, with motor - at ground. R4 then controls the amount of drive current and would definitely need reduction.

Comment: Since the output of the 555 is a totem pole, R2 can go away, and since Q2 is being pulled up to +5 by R3 and R4 when Q1 is cut off, R5 can also go away.

Comment: You're right about R2 - I was just being reflexively careful. And the schematic has an error which I had *intended* to correct but forgot - I intended to eliminate R3, which will work better than eliminating R5.

Comment: Goodness that's complicated? Why? What is it doing?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough - Yes, it is complicated. But it's working around the need to provide a lot of base current (about 20 mA) for Q3, plus maintaining the sign of the input signal. Think of Q1 as an inverter, Q2 as a source of base current for Q3, and Q3 as the actual motor drive. The high base current in Q3 is needed to drive it into saturation - if you don't provide this sort of currrent, Q3 will drop significant voltage, which will reduce the current available to the motor. All 3 transistors have base pull-up or pull-down resistors so they will be well-behaved.

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: Q1 is a low side switch. It's low side because it's just a simple switch and *isn't* switching anything that could be sensitive to ground being slightly above ground.

R1 is for limiting current to Q1. I don't understand how to choose 1k; should I be looking for max I_{BE} on the data sheet? What is R2 for (and how do you choose its value)? Don't understand "totem pole".

R3 is for limiting current to Q1. The N3904 data sheet gives max collector current of 200mA and 5 / 0.2 = 250 which is miles away from 10k.

Comment: The source 555 is identified as working off 5v, so the output will swing from 0 to (about) 5 volts. 1k is just a handy standard resistance. 10k would work perfectly well. R2 makes sure that no base current is driven into Q1 if, for instance, the 555 fails open, and is typically 10 times the base resistor.. With the collector of Q1 driven to ground, or actually about 0.2 volts or so, R4 will set the base current of Q2. Working backwards from the requirements on Q3 (about 150 mA), the base current of Q3 will need to be about 1/10 the collector current,so about 12 to15 mA.

Comment: With the voltage across R6 being about 4 volts, setting R6 to 330 ohms will produce 12 mA. So Q2 collector current will be about 12 mA, and Q2's base current should be at least 1.2 mA. A value of 4.7 k would be very close to the requirement. However, I used 1k for R4 just to keep the number of different resistor values down. And at 1k the power dissipation in R4 will only be about 16 mW, so going to this more aggressive base drive will not cause heating problems.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough  So, overall, using 1k base resistors is a result of my being lazy - and trying to design a circuit which the OP would find easy to build. It is not optimized, but the current and voltages are low enough that there is no need for optimization. Use of 10k base pulldown/pullup resistors is just insurance to make perfectly sure that leakage currents in the first two stages don't cause problems, and using a 10x value compared to base resistance is just a handy rule of thumb. Again, the circuit really doesn't need optimization, so rules of thumb are appropriate here.